# How do I make an angular component render in other component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-components

I've made an ionic and angular project, but I'm having some difficulties making it work, here is the  [sourcecode](https://github.com/nitram9876/Inventar.git), The main issues that I'm having is using the navbar component within the innsjekk and utsjekk components. I've added the  selector and there isn't any errors but it doesn't render. Also in the popover component, I added a routerLink to the profile component but nothing happens when I click it.

popover.component.html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button routerLink="/profil" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Profil</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngIf="isAdmin">
    <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button (click)="admin()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Admin</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>
    <ion-button (click)="logut()" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
      <ion-label>Log ut</ion-label>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

innsjekk.component.html:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <p>Hello world</p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you make the code runnable here on stackoverflow or in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add the components to the module declarations. Doing so fixed it all, I tried building the project then i got errors explaining the problem.

home.module.ts:

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { HomePage } from './home.page';
 import { NavbarComponent } from './../components/navbar/navbar.component';
    
 import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
 import { AdminComponent } from '../admin/admin.component';
 import { InnsjekkComponent } from '../innsjekk/innsjekk.component';
 import { PopoverComponent } from '../components/popover/popover.component';
 import { LogoutComponent } from '../components/logout/logout.component';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        HomePageRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [HomePage, NavbarComponent, AdminComponent, InnsjekkComponent, InnsjekkComponent, PopoverComponent, LogoutComponent],
      exports: [NavbarComponent]
    })
    export class HomePageModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass HTML as parameter to component, there are a lot of ways, with benefits and limitations. Mostly different:

1. Content projection. Search for `<ng-content>`. (most simple but has huge limitations)
2. Pass template as parameter. Search for `@ContentChildren`, `TemplateRef`, `ViewContainerRef`, structural directives. (flexible)
3. Pass component's type as `@Input` and render it inside another (using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`, `[ngComponentOutlet]`, etc.). (looks dirty)

They require a bit helping code. There can be some 'perversions' with them. Сhoice depends on many reasons.

share